# Installed C compiler now how can I import number theory functions?

Tags: primes

I have installed the CODE BLOCKS C COMPILER. Now I would use it for number theory. I need to import functions like is_probableprime or factor for checking extremely large numbers. Could I import GWNUM library and how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org) library?  Even if you don't use it directly you can import the functions you need.

Comment: @rossum how can I run it?

Comment: Download it and follow the instructions.  Since I work in Java I just looked at the source code and translated the parts I wanted into Java, so I don't actually run it.